# Python dummy statement for nothing or nop when indent expected

Tags: python

I recall there was a dummy statement that was the equivalent of do nothing or fill in the blank space after the `if`, `elif`, `else`, and `for` statements to keep the expected indentation.

The below example will not work

```
if True:
    #I want to simply pass this branch
    # ... NOP command here
else:
    print "False"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for `pass`?

Comment: Alternatively, when using `if variable_to_test`, invert the test: `if not variable_to_test: print "False"`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's `pass`:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

In Python 3 there's also the ellipsis `...`*, which wasn't really meant for this, but is also sometimes used:

```
def foo():
    ...
```

Semantically, I would expect to see `...` when that part isn't written *yet*, as a stub, and `pass` when there's never going to be code there.

---

<sup>* The ellipsis also exists in Python 2, but can't be used outside the square brackets in something like `foobar[...]`.</sup>

Comment: is `...` available in python 2?

Comment: @RaduIonescu See my edit. Technically yes, but not usable in that way.

Comment: Another options is "docstring"/string.  e.g. `"..."`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `pass` command to achieve this

```
if True:
    pass
else:
    print "False"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pass` statement like this:

```
if True:
    pass
else:
    print "False"
```